# Airflow dags are getting stuck in "running" state indefinitely

Tags: celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

My dags are getting stuck in "running" state indefinitely.
Even when I mark them as "failed" and rerun them again it is still getting stuck. When I check on the airflow UI the dag is in the "running" state :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po7D9.png)

When I check my airflow celery logs the last lines are the following and nothing else happened :

```
[...]
[2021-05-24 14:14:31,486] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/******.py
[2021-05-24 14:14:31,490] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/******.py
[2021-05-24 14:14:31,498] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/******.py
[2021-05-24 14:14:31,505] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/******.py
[2021-05-24 14:14:31,502] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/******.py
[2021-05-24 14:14:31,508] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/******.py
[2021-05-24 14:14:56,679: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-23] Running <TaskInstance: ***** 2021-05-24T06:14:30.718313+00:00 [queued]> on host **********
[2021-05-24 14:14:56,682: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-21] Running <TaskInstance: ***** 2021-05-24T06:14:30.718313+00:00 [queued]> on host **********
[2021-05-24 14:14:56,719: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] Running <TaskInstance: ***** 2021-05-24T06:14:30.718313+00:00 [queued]> on host **********
[2021-05-24 14:14:56,722: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-18] Running <TaskInstance: ***** 2021-05-24T06:14:30.718313+00:00 [queued]> on host **********
[2021-05-24 14:14:56,742: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-26] Running <TaskInstance: ***** 2021-05-24T06:14:30.718313+00:00 [queued]> on host **********
[2021-05-24 14:14:56,754: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-28] Running <TaskInstance: *****A1 2021-05-24T06:14:30.718313+00:00 [queued]> on host **********
```

Below are some of the logs I got from the scheduler :

```
[2021-05-24 14:09:18,552] {scheduler_job.py:1006} INFO - DAG *** has 32/32 running and queued tasks
[2021-05-24 14:09:18,552] {scheduler_job.py:1014} INFO - Not executing <TaskInstance: **** 2021-05-24 05:45:57.736363+00:00 [scheduled]> since the number of tasks running or queued from DAG **** is >= to the DAG's
task concurrency limit of 32
```

.

```
[...]
/home/ubuntu/****                                                                                      1           0  0.65s           2021-05-23T07:46:28
/home/ubuntu/****                                                                                      1           0  0.56s           2021-05-23T07:46:27
/home/ubuntu/****                                                                                      1           0  0.47s           2021-05-23T07:46:54
/home/ubuntu/****                                                                                      1           0  1.18s           2021-05-23T07:47:03
/home/ubuntu/****                                                                                      2           0  1.25s           2021-05-23T07:46:20
/home/ubuntu/****                                                                                      2           0  1.26s           2021-05-23T07:46:20
/home/ubuntu/****                                                                                      2           0  1.30s           2021-05-23T07:46:19
/home/ubuntu/****                                                                                    113           0  2.91s           2021-05-23T07:47:05
/home/ubuntu/****                                                                                    459           0  7.85s           2021-05-23T07:46:38
================================================================================

[2021-05-23 15:47:58,271] {scheduler_job.py:182} INFO - Started process (PID=13794) to work on ********
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,272] {scheduler_job.py:161} INFO - Closing parent pipe
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,273] {scheduler_job.py:629} INFO - Processing file ******************** for tasks to queue
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,273] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from ********************
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,273] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing ******** took 0.014 seconds
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,274] {scheduler_job.py:641} WARNING - No viable dags retrieved from ************
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,275] {scheduler_job.py:182} INFO - Started process (PID=13797) to work on **************
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,275] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing ******** took 0.014 seconds
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,276] {scheduler_job.py:629} INFO - Processing file ************** for tasks to queue
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,276] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from **************
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,277] {scheduler_job.py:641} WARNING - No viable dags retrieved from **************
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,278] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing ******** took 0.016 seconds
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,281] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing ******** took 0.016 seconds
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,285] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing ******** took 0.016 seconds
[2021-05-23 15:47:58,287] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing ************** took 0.015 seconds
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,300] {scheduler_job.py:161} INFO - Closing parent pipe
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,302] {scheduler_job.py:182} INFO - Started process (PID=13932) to work on *****************.py
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,303] {scheduler_job.py:629} INFO - Processing file ***************** for tasks to queue
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,304] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from ***************** 
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,434] {scheduler_job.py:641} WARNING - No viable dags retrieved from *****************
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,445] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing ***************** took 0.144 seconds
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,452] {scheduler_job.py:161} INFO - Closing parent pipe
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,455] {scheduler_job.py:182} INFO - Started process (PID=13934) to work on *****************
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,456] {scheduler_job.py:629} INFO - Processing file ***************** for tasks to queue
[2021-05-23 15:48:02,456] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from *****************
[2021-05-23 15:48:03,457] {scheduler_job.py:161} INFO - Closing parent pipe
[2021-05-23 15:48:03,460] {scheduler_job.py:182} INFO - Started process (PID=13959) to work on ********
[2021-05-23 15:48:03,461] {scheduler_job.py:629} INFO - Processing file ******** for tasks to queue
[2021-05-23 15:48:03,461] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from ********
[2021-05-23 15:48:03,501] {scheduler_job.py:641} WARNING - No viable dags retrieved from *****************
[2021-05-23 15:48:03,514] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing ***************** took 1.061 seconds
[2021-05-23 15:48:04,547] {scheduler_job.py:639} INFO - DAG(s) dict_keys(['****']) retrieved from *******
[2021-05-23 15:48:04,559] {dag.py:1824} INFO - Sync 1 DAGs
[2021-05-23 15:48:04,568] {dag.py:2280} INFO - Setting next_dagrun for **** to 2021-05-23T04:00:00+00:00
[2021-05-23 15:48:04,572] {scheduler_job.py:190} INFO - Processing ********took 1.115 seconds
[2021-05-23 15:48:05,538] {dag_processing.py:1092} INFO - Finding 'running' jobs without a recent heartbeat
[2021-05-23 15:48:05,539] {dag_processing.py:1096} INFO - Failing jobs without heartbeat after 2021-05-23 07:43:05.539102+00:00
[2021-05-23 15:48:05,546] {scheduler_job.py:161} INFO - Closing parent pipe
[2021-05-23 15:48:05,549] {scheduler_job.py:182} INFO - Started process (PID=14077) to work on ********
[2021-05-23 15:48:05,549] {scheduler_job.py:629} INFO - Processing file ********for tasks to queue
[2021-05-23 15:48:05,550] {dagbag.py:451} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from ********
```

To make it work I have to :

- Empty the running slots and queued slots in Admin > Pools by setting the tasks as Failed
- Restart airflow celery worker

Saw on github that people have recently face this issue:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13542

Link to my github issue:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/15978

---

Also I noticed a weird behavior with Airflow backfilling. I noticed that my previous dags are still queing and running even after doing the following :

- Setting catchup_by_default=False in airflow.cfg
- Setting catchup=False in the DAG definition
- Using LatestOnlyOperator

Would appreciate if someone can help me solving this issue, thank you!

---

**Configuration:**

Apache Airflow version: 2.0.2

OS : Ubuntu 18.04.3 (AWS EC2)

Install tools: celery = 4.4.7, redis = 3.5.3

Comment: Did you manage to get this fixed? I have almost the same problem. Now in 2.2.2 version